# Unable to getfocus and start editing an EditText in TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window

Tags: android, android-edittext, overlay

I'm creating a floating `EditText` that needs to be on top of all windows. This is the code i'm using:

```
public class FlyingPaste extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private List<View> bubbles;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private boolean isbubblexpanded;
    private ImageView bubble;
    private LinearLayout linearEditor;
    private LinearLayout linearBubble;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        bubbles = new ArrayList<View>();
        isbubblexpanded = false;
        Log.d("service","created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final View bubbleItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flying_paste, null);

        Log.d("service","onStartCommand");

        ImageView paste = (ImageView) bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_pasteit);
        final EditText pTxt = (EditText)bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_editText);
        pTxt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        pTxt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    pTxt.requestFocusFromTouch();
                    Log.d("Touch","got"); //HERE THE LOG MESSAGE IS SHOWN BUT NO SOFT KEYBOARD APPEAR xD
                    return true;
            }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ImageView minimize = (ImageView)bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_minimize);
        minimize.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggleBubble();
            }
        });

        bubble = (ImageView)bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_bubble);
        linearBubble = (LinearLayout)bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_bubbleLinearLayout);
        linearEditor = (LinearLayout)bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_linearEditor);

        bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_close).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windowManager.removeView(bubbleItem);
            }
        });

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        bubbleItem.findViewById(R.id.flying_actbar).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(bubbleItem, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

        bubble.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (params.x > (initialX-5)) {
                            if (params.x < (initialX+5)) {
                                if (params.y > (initialY-5)) {
                                    if (params.y < (initialY+5)) {
                                        toggleBubble();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(bubbleItem, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        bubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        linearEditor.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        addBubbleItem(bubbleItem, params);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void addBubbleItem(View bubbleItem, LayoutParams params) {
        bubbles.add(bubbleItem);
        windowManager.addView(bubbleItem, params);
        Log.d("service","addBubbleItem");

    }

    public void toggleBubble() {
        if (isBubbleExpanded()) {
            linearEditor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearBubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isbubblexpanded = false;
        }
        else {
            linearBubble.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearEditor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isbubblexpanded = true;
        }
    }

    private boolean isBubbleExpanded() {
        return isbubblexpanded;
    }

    public void removeBubbleItem(View bubbleItem) {
        bubbles.remove(bubbleItem);
        windowManager.removeView(bubbleItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        for (View bubbleItem : bubbles) {
            removeBubbleItem(bubbleItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except that when i click on the EditText (`pTxt` in the code above) the log message `Touch`,`got` is shown in the console but <del>the editText doesn't get focus nor</del> the soft keyboard is not shown. Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that if i remove the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` the EditText works as it's intended to do but the soft `back button` doesn't work then.

**EDIT2:** I need to correct myself, the EditText get the focus but the SoftInput keyboard is not shown

Comment: Did you check in various devices? See if its some device specific issue or some OS specific issue.

Comment: I'll check ASAP and let you know. Ty.

Comment: Ok, i tested it on a Galaxy S4, A chinese phone(ZOPO) and a LG nexus 4. It's the same on all 3 devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**public static final int TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY**
Window type: system overlay windows, which need to be displayed on top of everything else. These windows must not take input focus, or they will interfere with the keyguard. In multiuser systems shows only on the owning user's window.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY

**EDIT :**

after a few days of research, I found a library in XDA developers which will help us to do the task. please refer the link.....It really works and they provide lots of samples, which will help us to easily understand the library functionalities.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531

Comment: I will check ASAP and let you know.

Comment: Edittext not working with that library on Android 6.0

Comment: @lacas please check the examples they provided with the library. I am sure that it works since I have tested them myself and I have customized it for one my old project. So please give one more try.

Answer (score 1):

although it is depreciated but it will work.
while specifying your `window params` add this flag:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
```

e.g.

```
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    ...
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do this other than programming your own Software-Keyboard that is part of the system_alert (overlay) Layout..

Note that if you are using a softwarekeyboard to input when the overlay is shown it will close and it will not open again before the overlay is removed from the windowmanager. So it's not that you can't use a edittext inside the overlay it is that you can't use a soft-keyboard to input into any textfield while the system-alert is showing.

So I guess that the android-internal overlays like bluetooth-coupling password input have a special keyboard that is part of the overlay.

Don't know anything about that facebook app though..